# Line not breaking in IE (flexbox)

Tags: internet-explorer, text, alignment, flexbox

I used the following technique to vertically center the text in a DIV:

```
.nav-wrap>ul>li>a div{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content:center;
}
```

It's for the nav menu, one item looks like this (it's inside the LI item in UL):

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="training"><div>Online Training/Resources</div></a>
```

However, vertical alignment works fine in , but I have the problem in IE11 (and probably older ones). In Chrome and Firefox, if the text line is longer than the width of the container, it breaks into two lines, and stays aligned, just like it should. But in IE, it doesn't break, it expands out of the div, and overlaps with the other nav items. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a width on your elements that are inside of the flexbox.

It is hard to tell what exact method you are trying to do and why you are using this method to accomplish that goal but you may need to place the flexbox on the anchor tag in the li or add a paragraph tag within the div in order to have something you can put the width on of adding a width directly to the div doesn't work.

Try to provide more code next time.